# How to connect the "clicked" signal and "key_press_event" to the same callback function?

Tags: c, gtk

What I wanted to do is to connect the mouse click "clicked" signal and the keypress "key_press_event" signal to the same callback function. The code started off like this:

```
static void s_up(GtkWidget *btn,
                 gpointer  data)
{
    code ...
}

...

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ...
    g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(s_up), NULL);
}
```

It handled mouse clicks just fine. Then I wanted to add keyboard presses to it. So I changed the code to

```
static void s_up(GtkWidget   *btn,
                 GdkEventKey *event
                 gpointer    data)
{
    if(event->keyval == 's')
        more code ...
}

...

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ...

    g_signal_connect(button, "key_press_event", G_CALLBACK(s_up), NULL);
}
```

It worked when I press "s" on my keyboard.

My question is how to connect both signals to the same `s_up` callback function? Other than the obvious problem of `if(event->keyval == 's')`, I tried calling both `gtk_signal_connect`, and when I clicked on the button, I got SegFault pointing to `s_up`. Pressing "s" didn't do anything. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a wrapper function to indirectly call the same callback:

```
static void
callback(GtkWidget *button, gpointer data)
{
    /* TODO */
}

static gboolean
wrapper(GtkWidget *button, GdkEventKey *event, gpointer data)
{
    if (event->keyval == 's')
        callback(button, data);
    return FALSE;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* TODO */
    g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(callback), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(button, "key-press-event", G_CALLBACK(wrapper), NULL);
    /* TODO */
}
```

If you do not use `data` you can also use a single function, but in my opinion the complexity introduced is not worth the effort:

```
static gboolean
callback(GtkWidget *button, GdkEventKey *event)
{
    if (event != NULL && event->keyval == 's')
        callback(button, data);
    return FALSE;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* TODO */
    g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(callback), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(button, "key-press-event", G_CALLBACK(callback), NULL);
    /* TODO */
}
```

To be able to understand the latter example you must know that:

1. the return value is discarded if not used (you **must** return `FALSE` from a key press event if you don't want to stop the event handling);
2. the extra arguments in callbacks are silently discarded.

This means when `callback()` is called by a click you have the **data** value (`NULL`) in **event** while when it is called from a key press the **event** is properly set and **data** is silently discarded.

This in turn means if you add a check for `event != NULL` in your second example things start working.

Answer (score 4):

You can't connect both signals directly to the same signal handler because they require different arguments.

The reason why you get a segmentation fault is because `event->keyval` only makes sense when you receive a `key-press-event`. When you receive a `clicked` event the second argument will be `NULL`, since it maps to the `gpointer` argument supplied with `clicked` events and you've set that to `NULL` when you installed the signal handler, so `event` will be `NULL`.

If the reason why you want to connect both signals to the same handler is that you have common code that should run no matter which signal triggered it, then the solution is to have one handler for each signal and a third function with common code that both of them can call.

Comment: I'll add that `gtk_signal_connect` has been obsolete for some years now, he should use `g_signal_connect` instead.